# How to solve Poisson's equation for the potential?

Tags: symmetry, potential, density, greens-functions

I'm working with a spherical symmetric system and have found it to have mass density $$\rho=\frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \frac{dM(r)}{dr}.$$  Poisson's equation says $\nabla^2 \Omega(r) $ = $4\pi G \rho(r)$.

I'm confused on how to solve this equation for the potential $\Omega$ given the $\rho$ that I found. Is there anyone that can advise or provide a starting point? I have been out of school and mathematics for a few years. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't really a calculation help site, but a starting point is looking up $\nabla^2$ in spherical coordinates and writing that out

Comment: You need more information, since your equation for $\rho$ holds for any spherical mass distribution.  If $M(r)$ is the amount of mass located between the origin and radius $r$, then your equation for $\rho$ always holds.  To find the potential, you need to specify what the mass distribution actually is.  That is, you need to know explicitly what either $\rho(r)$ or $M(r)$ is.